# How to use parameter from Gitlab in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, environment-variables, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK and want to use parameters stored in Gitlab as variables in CDK build.

Someone tried something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions found:

1. Create custom variable in Gitlab (with the same repository as project) in two ways:

   - In pipeline file with project (not sensitive data)
   - In project properties in Gitlab (recomended solution if want to store sensitive params as credentials - those parameters should not be stored with project in file)
2. Declare custom env in main CDK file (e.x. `const CUSTOM_ENV = ${CUSTOM_ENV}`)
3. Call `cdk deploy` with created parameter e.g. `cdk deploy $CUSTOM_ENV` and the variable will be automatically delivered by Gitlab.

More details how to declare variables - [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project)